# Setting a default value of the current time to a datetime column in an Ecto migration

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm looking for something similar to this SQL.

```
column_name my_timestamp_column NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Note that I require that the name of the column be specifiable, so the `timestamps` macro is not suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute SQL in migration like this

```
def change do
  execute("ALTER TABLE some_table ADD some_column timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
end
```